# Proof verification for $\int_{E}f =\lim \int_{E}f_{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

This is from Folland's analysis. Problem 2.13

> > Consider a measure space $(X, M, \mu)$. Suppose $\{f_{n}\} \in L^{+}, f_{n} \rightarrow f$ pointwise and $\int f = \lim \int f_{n} < \infty$. Then $\int_{E} f = \lim \int_{E} f_{n}$ for all $E \in M$. However, this need not be true if $\int f = \lim \int f_{n} = \infty$

Now it seems like a lot of the answers given are a lot more complicated than what I got so I probably made a mistake. I would like to ask which step is incorrect:

We have $\lim \int f_n-\int f=0$ so $\lim \int (f_n- f)=0$ which is possible because all $f_n$ and $f$ are integrable. Also since $f_n \to f$ pointwise, if we multiply the integrand by $\chi_E$, the integral is still $0$ so $\lim \int (f_n- f)\chi_E=0$ which implies $\lim \int f_n\chi_E-\int f\chi_E=0$ which gives us our result.

Comment: Could you elaborate on *"Also since $f_n\to f$ pointwise, if we multiply the integrand by $\chi_E$, the integral is still $0$"*?

Comment: Well, my reasoning is that $f_n \to f$ so $lim(f_n-f)\chi_E=0$, thus $lim \int (f_n-f)\chi_E=0$

Comment: by the way, is the first step justified? we are actually able to say the difference of the integral is the integral of the difference right in this case?

Comment: i think i know what the problem is ..basically i assumed since $lim \int f_n =\int f$, it is immediate that $ lim \int f_n \chi_E= \int f \chi_E$, but that is not true (or at least not obvious unless one can prove that is the case).